# Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3 Send failed

Tags: php, zend-framework, pop3, zend-mail

I have created a script using the Zend Framework. The goal is that the script checks the e-mail. When I connect to a pop3 account that isn't on the same domain as the webhosting (f.ex hosting is on arkreport.be and the e-mail is info@my-domain.com), it works. But when I connect to a mail account on the same hostingaccount, it wouldn't work.

Could this be a server problem? My webhosts asks me more information about the way I connect, but i can't give them more than a short explanation of all used codes.

Is there an alternative perhaps. The emailuseraccount has a % in it, perhaps that is a problem... I don't know :)

This is the error

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'read failed - connection closed?' in /var/www/html/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Pop3.php:174 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Pop3.php(222): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Pop3->readResponse(false) #1 /var/www/html/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Pop3.php(282): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Pop3->request('PASS passw') #2 /var/www/html/library/Zend/Mail/Storage/Pop3.php(191): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Pop3->login('facturen%arkrep...', 'oj1rak') #3 /var/www/html/application/default/controllers/CronController.php(76): Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3->__construct(Array) #4 /var/www/html/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): CronController->checkmailAction() #5 /var/www/html/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('checkmailAction') #6 /var/www/html/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #7 /var/www/h in /var/www/html/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Pop3.php on line 174

Answer (score 0):

Your host is probably rejecting the bad character "%".
Make a new username without special characters like "%" use only letters.